# Firebase database - How to get the value directy under the key? (not under a custom class)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have the following data structure inside `Firebase` real time database. I have no ideas how to extract the content.

My `firebase` real-time database structure:

```
root
|--inGroup
  |--#userID
    |--#randomId:(the string I want to extract is here)
    |--#randomId2:(the string I want to extract is here)
    |--#randomIdX:(the string I want to extract is here)
```

Any one can teach me how to extract it in my android app?

**My code:**

The part for extracting the content from `firebase` db:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference groupInviteRef = database.getReference("inGroup").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

groupInviteRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            -----I am not sure what to fill in here--------
        }
    }
}
```

The part for saving the data I want to extract

```
//Insert a record into InGroup tree
DatabaseReference inGroupRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("inGroup").child(uid);
inGroupRef.push().setValue(groupId);
```

I don't know how to extract the string from the database because:

1) Usually, what would use `datasnapshot.getValue(XXXX.Class)` to get the attribute of the value, but this time, it is a string itself instead of a custom class i setup myself.

2) I tried to use `datasnapshot.getvalue(String.class)`. But got this error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
```

Can anyone teach me how to extract the information i want? Or I must put in a custom class when when doing `push().setValue()`?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, i make it using the following piece of code, not sure why at the beginning it doesn't work.

```
groupInviteRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String value = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                Log.d("val",value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Although you have solved your problem, the reason it was not working was because you had used same varibale name in for loop as the argument in onDataChange, i.e. dataSnapshot

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = noteDataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : noteDataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        snapshot.getKey() // YOUR VALUE
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. (I tried to print out noteDataSnapshot.getChildrenCount under the first for loop, it print out 0). So, I believe the data i want to print out is not a child?